# How to convert two different date formats from a pandas dataframe column into same format?

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-formatting

I have two different date formats in a pandas column such as - `DD-MM-YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY` and I want to convert them into the same format.

I tried using the code -

```
data['SALE DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['SALE DATE']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

but this converts the dates into 
`DD/MM/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY` into the output - data['SALE DATE']

[image]

I want a python solution to overcome this problem. Any leads will be very helpful.

Comment: Could you please include some source data, as well as some expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have added the sample input and output to the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most intuitive solution is to write a custom conversion function,
someting like:

```
def myDateConv(tt):
    sep = tt[2]
    if sep == '-':
        return pd.to_datetime(tt, format='%d-%m-%Y')
    elif sep == '/':
        return pd.to_datetime(tt, format='%m/%d/%Y')
    else:
        return tt
```

and then pass it as a *converter* for the column in question:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', converters={'Date': myDateConv})
```

I prepared a CSV file, which read with *read_csv* without any
custom converter gave the original content and both columns of
*object* type:

```
         Date Input format
0  03-05-2020   DD-MM-YYYY
1  05/07/2020   MM/DD/YYYY
```

But reading the same file with the above converter gave:

```
        Date Input format
0 2020-05-03   DD-MM-YYYY
1 2020-05-07   MM/DD/YYYY
```

with *Date* column of *datetime64[ns]* type and both dates from
May, just as intended.

Or if you have this DataFrame from other source and you want to
convert this column, run:

```
df.Date = df.Date.apply(myDateConv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved my problem and I learnt how to solve such issues :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pandas version 1.xx you can use the following solution:

```
pd.to_datetime(["11-08-2018", "05-03-2016", "08/30/2017", "09/21/2018"], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

This gives the following result:

```
Index(['08/11/2018', '03/05/2016', '08/30/2017', '09/21/2018'], dtype='object')
```

... the important argument here is **dayfirst=True**.

See [`pd.to_datetime` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for more.