# pandas - replace string with values from dictionary based on the type of character?

Tags: python, pandas

Edit 2: showing sample raw data

```
# This will not match up exactly to the sample data I had provided in # original post as I was trying to do Minimum reproducable data

['NIFTY21JULFUT', 'BANKNIFTY19MAY31500CE', 'BANKNIFTY2131834800CE', 'DRREDDY20DEC5300CE', 'BANKNIFTY2090323800CE', 'BANKNIFTY2142231000PE', 'BANKNIFTY1931427800CE', 'BANKNIFTY2170134700PE', 'BANKNIFTY19SEP29800PE', 'BANKNIFTY20JUL22000CE', 'BANKNIFTY21JUN34700PE', 'BANKNIFTY20NOV29300CE', 'TCS20OCT2900CE', 'BANKNIFTY1911027500PE', 'BRITANNIA20JUL3900PE', 'NAUKRI22JAN5000PE', 'BANKNIFTY21APR33300CE', 'ICICIBANK21MAR580PE', 'BANKNIFTY1932029800CE', 'BANKNIFTY20JAN31200CE', 'HDFCBANK20NOV1320PE', 'BANKNIFTY1941130300CE', 'RELIANCE21AUG2060PE', 'NMDC21JUN190CE', 'BANKNIFTY20O2224600CE', 'BANKNIFTY2190235500PE', 'BANKNIFTY18D2026800PE', 'BANKNIFTY2070921000PE', 'ITC22JAN225CE', 'BANKNIFTY21APR33700CE', 'NESTLEIND22MAR17400CE', 'NIFTY19JUNFUT', 'BANKNIFTY1950928900CE', 'BANKNIFTY1911727600CE', 'BANKNIFTY20N0525700CE', 'TCS20OCT2750CE', 'SIEMENS22FEB2360CE', 'BANKNIFTY20JAN31000CE', 'BANKNIFTY1932029700PE', 'BANKNIFTY2031224200CE', 'BANKNIFTY1910327400CE', 'BANKNIFTY2131837000CE', 'BANKNIFTY2161736000CE', 'NIFTY21SEPFUT', 'BANKNIFTY20OCT25100CE', 'BANKNIFTY20FEBFUT', 'BANKNIFTY1940430500CE', 'AXISBANK20MAYFUT', 'NIFTY21DECFUT', 'PERSISTENT21OCT4000CE', 'BANKNIFTY19JAN27200PE', 'BANKNIFTY20D1730800PE', 'BANKNIFTY2051419000CE', 'KOTAKBANK21AUG1740CE', 'BANKNIFTY2070221300CE', 'BANKNIFTY20MAY16600PE', 'BANKNIFTY2131835000CE', 'MOTHERSUMI20MAR110PE', 'BANKNIFTY1950928900PE', 'BANKNIFTY20MAR20900CE', 'BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE', 'BANKNIFTY2150632900CE', 'BANKNIFTY20DEC28700PE', 'BANKNIFTY2081320800PE', 'RELIANCE21MAR2300CE', 'BANKNIFTY2061120600PE', 'BANKNIFTY2072323000PE', 'BANKNIFTY20O1523600CE', 'BANKNIFTY2061121000PE', 'BANKNIFTY19JUL29100CE', 'BANKNIFTY20O1523700CE', 'DRREDDY20DEC4750PE', 'BANKNIFTY19FEB26800CE', 'BANKNIFTY1940430400PE', 'BANKNIFTY2020630900PE', 'BANKNIFTY2030530000PE', 'BANKNIFTY1931428300PE', 'BANKNIFTY20D1029000PE', 'BANKNIFTY2050719500PE', 'BANKNIFTY1941129900PE', 'BANKNIFTY2091722500CE', 'MARUTI19FEB6900CE', 'BANKNIFTY2012331500CE', 'ICICIBANK21MAR650CE', 'BANKNIFTY21JANFUT', 'BANKNIFTY19O2429100PE', 'BANKNIFTY22MARFUT', 'BANKNIFTY20JAN30600CE', 'BANKNIFTY1962030400PE', 'RELIANCE22FEB2380CE', 'RELIANCE21JUN2100PE', 'BAJAJ-AUTO21NOVFUT', 'ICICIBANK21MAR560PE', 'BANKNIFTY19JAN27000CE', 'PNB19MAR75CE', 'BANKNIFTY1910327300CE', 'BANKNIFTY19D1932000PE', 'BANKNIFTY2091022600PE', 'BANKNIFTY19OCT30200CE', 'TCS21MAR3120CE']
```

Edit 1: Showing how the date column is being created.

The initial file doesn't have dates. Please note I have created this sample, the real data has a lot of varied `Symbol`

```
Symbol
ADANIPORTS30418FUT
ADANIPORTS31818FUT
ADANIPORTS42219FUT
ADANIPORTS53019FUT
ADANIPORTSJAN19FUT
ADANIPORTSDEC20FUT
ADANIPORTSD0819FUT
dtype=object
# split, on second thought there might be a problem here as the D
# split should not happen
df[['Symbol', 'year', 'month']] = df['Symbol'].str.split("(\d\d)", n=1, expand=True)

df['year'] = '20' + df['year']

df['month'] = df['month'].str[:3]

df['date'] = df['month'] + '-' + df['year']

# tried pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Error on trying `pd.to_datetime`:

> dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: D08-2019

Here is the sample series:

```
df = 
date
304-2018
318-2018
422-2019
530-2019
JAN-2019
DEC-2020
D08-2019
```

The sample `dictionary`:

```
sample_dict = {3 : 'MAR', 4 : 'APR', 5:'MAY', 'D': 'DEC'}
```

I want to `replace()` or some other method if the first three characters are digits example `304-2018`. Then based on the `dictionary` it should convert to: `'MAR-2018'`.

In the case of first character `D` and the next two being digits, use dictionary and convert to DEC-Year example: `D08-2019` to become `'DEC-2019'` while not changing anything if the first character is D but the next two are also type string.

I tried:

`df['date'].replace(to_replace='\d\d\d', .....`

...but I'm stumped by what to put in value.

Expected output:

```
df =
date
MAR-2018
MAR-2018
APR-2019
MAY-2019
JAN-2019
DEC-2020
DEC-2019
```

Comment: So you want to replace date strings of form 'MDD' e.g. '304' with the abbreviated monthname (e.g. 'MAR') from your dictionary. But how do you know the 'M' part isn't sometimes two digits? What does your dictionary define for October, November? Is October 'O'? That could be a bit too close to '0' for comfort...

Comment: What if it starts with `J`, should it be `Jan`, `June` or `July` ?

Comment: Also, we need you to post `df.info()` so we can see the dtype of`date` column; is it string, python datetime, pandas datetime64...? This is really important to know. And in fact, you can prevent the date being misread by `pd.read_csv` options relating to date, see in particular `converters` argument, since you'll need a custom converter for `date` column.

Comment: Related: [How to convert two different date formats from a pandas dataframe column into same format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118165/how-to-convert-two-different-date-formats-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column-into-sa)

Comment: @smci @Psidom if the month is double digit in number the date format changes to month's starting letter followed by date(dd) so `January`, `June` and `July` will not be `J`.

Comment: @smci the date column is being generated from another column and is `dtype` `O`.

Comment: @Sid: then show us the code that generates the `date` column from another column X. Essentially it sounds like the date was read in badly, or the dtype of column X is wrong (convert into a pandas datetime, already!), so better to fix those first than end up writing this sort of workaround.  dtype 'O' only means Python 'object'/string, it usually is not a great dtype for formatted columns.

Comment: @smci updated the question. I am checking the code again at my side.

Comment: @Sid while it looks like there _might_ be a date there... are you sure you're not reading too much into it and it just doesn't happen to be a coincidence it looks like it could be parsed as one?

Comment: Could you do for instance a `df['Symbol'].sample(100).tolist()` and provide that in a code block in an [edit]?

Comment: @JonClements There is definitely a date as these are futures/options contract symbols which are of the general format: tickerExpiry(date)Instrument_type. The Expiry can be monthly in which case it comes out as: `MonthYear(last two from 2022 i.e. 22)`. If its a weekly contract `MonthDDYear(last two)`. Incase the `Month` is double digit they convert it to the first letter of the month. Posting sample as an edit.

Comment: @Sid that's err... quite an "inventive" way of producing easy to use data :p

Comment: @JonClements haha yes, the broker reports are giving me headaches. My look back `db` threw some errors and I thought I will use the broker reports.

Comment: @Sid so the actual sample seems even more convoluted... are you asking purely in this case about the ADANIPORTS ? As - glancing over the sample... you could well have some branching logic based on the prefix and suffix... (there seems to be the identifier at the front, a very common combination of ending characters (FUT/CE/PE etc...) and confusing bits in the middle)... no idea what BANKNIFTY1941130300CE is meant to be though...

Comment: `print(df['Symbol'].str.extract('([A-Z]+)$').value_counts().to_dict()) # {('CE',): 53, ('PE',): 38, ('DECFUT',): 1, ('FEBFUT',): 1, ('JANFUT',): 1, ('JULFUT',): 1, ('JUNFUT',): 1, ('MARFUT',): 1, ('MAYFUT',): 1, ('NOVFUT',): 1, ('SEPFUT',): 1}` looks kind of a reasonable start to start whittling away

Comment: @JonClements Thank you. I think it's a better idea to focus on the sample series i.e. `304-2018`, ......., `D08-2019` and the question from there. I can get all the data distilled down to these type of numbers. Any ideas? Sorry for the late reply.